# Get exhaustive domain user rights on domain with Powerview/Powersploit

Tags: active-directory

I am connected to a Windows workstation with a basic domain user account.

I have downloaded and installed Powersploit. I have also tried with Powerview.

There is a command called `Get-DomainObjectAcl`. This command shows us ACL on AD objects for a given user.

But this user has groups. And some groups have memberships to other groups.

I don't know if `Get-DomainObjectAcl` is able to follow groups. It seems it just gives the ACLs associated with the user itself.

Is there a way to automate this and fetch all ACLs for user groups?